# Find string( js search and regex) with backslashes and digits between them

Tags: javascript, string, search, replace, substring

I want to find a string in style of '/89/'

Let's say I have this string: '78/12/98 something else' and want to transform it into 'something else'.

And let's assume that not every string has to contain this type of expression(if the search function returns -1 we do nothing).

How to do this?

```
let string = '78/12/98 something else';

let index = string.search(look for description);

if(index!=-1){ 
    string = string.substring(index+5);
}

console.log(string);
// OUTPUT: 'something else'

let string2 ='no double backslashes with digits between them';

index = string.search(look for description);

if(index!=-1){ 
    string = string.substring(index+5);
}
console.log(string2);
// OUTPUT: 'no double backslashes with digits between them';
```

Comment: Please submit a minimal, complete and reproducible example with your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern you are looking for is 
*Two digits / Two digits / Two digits `space` **anything** endline* 
`\d\d/\d\d/\d\d\s(.*$)`
or maybe 
*Zero or Two digits / Zero or Two digits / Zero or Two digits `space` **anything** endline*
`\d{0,2}/\d{0,2}/\d{0,2}\s(.*$)`
replace with
`\1` It will replace with anything it matched inside `()`.
For JS you can do as follow 
`let string = '78/12/98 something else';` 
`let patt = /\d{0,2}\/\d{0,2}\/\d{0,2}\s/; // Creates a regex patern`
`string = string.replace(patt, ''); // replace finds with ''`
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7BlS.png)

Comment: But how I will implement this?

Comment: I had to refresh my JS, checked it in my Chorme Dev console, it works

Comment: Ok, I found a different solution for this one, but I like this too, so I will accept it.